# How to handle window resizes in GTK4?

Tags: gtk, pygtk, gtk4

I am trying to build a virtualized grid container to display 100k+ files in PyGTK 4 on Fedora 35. I succeeded in creating the layout and scrolling support which works beautifully.

In order to support resizing of my application window, I need to react to changes its size. I already connected to the `notify` signal of the window and handle the `default-width`, `default-height`, `maximized` and `unmaximized` events to update the geometry of my layout. However, everytime I invoke `get_width()` of my widget/app window after the `maximized` event I only get the width **before** the window was maximized! Is this by design?

I've been trying pretty hard but I fail to come to a working solution for this simple problem. Can anyone help me?

### Edit

Here is some code to outline how I am trying to measure the window size. I modified the code to use `connect_after` instead of `connect`as proposed by @GüntherWagner. However, the behavior is the same for both methods:

```
class TestLayout(Gtk.ScrolledWindow):
  def on_realize(self, widget):
    ...
    self.get_root().connect_after('notify', self.on_notify)

  def on_notify(self, widget, param):
     if param.name in [..., 'maximized', 'unmaximized']:
        self.draw()

  def draw(self):
      self.width = self.get_width()
      self.height = self.get_height()
```

Comment: It sounds like you need a [tag:threading] timer.

Comment: I'll try that!  I already tried this but I probably used the wrong method..

Comment: @sylvester-kruin It works! Thank you for your help.  However, occasionally the application crashes because of a 'parent != null' assertion. That's the kind of race conditions to be expected with using timers since they do not integrate into the GTK update cycle. I played around with the timing and now it seems to be stable. I'd still appreciante if anyone could enlighten me on how this is supposed to be done in GTK4..

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about Gtk4; I've never used it before. But I'm sure there's lots of information here and/or elsewhere on the web.

Comment: Don't worry. You already helped me a lot. Regarding GTK4 there is not a lot of information on the web. Unfortunately the bindings are generated through introspection so there is no code-completion or any other IDE assistance. Most of the available documention is auto-generated from the C documentation. Only a few examples in this [tutorial](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but only for GTK3 which is considerably different.

Comment: I guess that's why I'm still using Gtk3. It has more documentation :-). Maybe I'll switch to Gtk4 when Gtk3 becomes deprecated... Anyway, good luck on your project and happy coding!

Comment: i think you have to connect the notify signal differently. If you connect_after it will have the new values. Basically how this works is: [notify] -> [default-handler] -> [notify_after] so you tried to access the values before the default-handler updated them.

Comment: @GüntherWagner Thank you for the tip! This sounds interesting and I will try it as soon as I find the time. However, I am curious because I cannot find any documentation about it? https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/?q=connect_after

Comment: Just search for g_signal_connect_after - https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.signal_connect_after.html